# "Dear Sir" or "Dear John" if you are addressing the VP of a company

Tags: politeness, greetings, correspondence

How to address the VP of a company or department? I have been told that addressing by name was not polite.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you knew him personally, it would certainly not be appropriate in the UK, and I imagine it would not be in the US either. Few men will object to being addressed by a stranger as 'Dear Sir'.

Comment: i am sorry , i am little confused here . If i don't know him how should i address ?

Comment: 'Dear Sir' should be OK. If you know his surname, then 'Dear Mr [surname]'. 'Dear Vice-President' might also be possible, but you should perhaps check first with someone in the company.

Comment: As a side note, @brainHax, do not put spaces before commas, periods, and question marks. That is not done in English. In fact, to my knowledge, for commas and periods it is not done in *any* language at all.

Answer (score 1):

"Sir" means "a respectful or formal term of address used to a man". Omit it, and you also omit respect. You use "Dear [name]" if the person you are addressing to is close to you.

If you are writing a business-related letter, do not omit "Sir" even if the CEO is your husband!